# Circuit to prevent spark from plugging Li-po batteries into motor driver with filtering capacitors

Tags: capacitance, circuit-design, inrush-current, spark

I have a motor driver that handles 2 150watt motors powered by 2 Li-po 12V batteries (connected in series). Obviously, I need filtering caps on my driver so I used 2 1200uF caps connected in parallel.

My issue is that every time I connect the batteries there is a spark because of the caps. How do I prevent this spark from happening? I am pretty sure that there has to be a nice solution for this. Also, the motors never have to run right after connecting the batteries.

Comment: the term you want to google for might be: inrush current limiter

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe it, it sounds like the inrush current caused by your capacitors charging up.

For that you could use a limiter, such as a thermistor, or a soft-start circuit, such as a large pass FET with an RC timing circuit. The latter's RC would turn the FET on slowly enough for the capacitors to charge smoothly but not so slowly that the FET gets hot (500 ms?).

Are you sure that your motor load is off when you plug in, though, and have you got any power-up circuitry to ensure this?

Comment: yes, I`m 100% sure that the motors will not start. The only instant load is a small LED and a MCU (atmega328) which drives the H bridge.

Comment: @VirgilLitan, I imagine your MCU may well have high-Z drift-high outputs until it's out of reset with crystal started and software has configured the I/O ports. During that time, maybe 5..10ms, what will the H-bridge do? Has it got resistors pulling its inputs inactive or suchlike? Or can its inputs float to enabling driving?

Comment: yes, it has pull-down resistors, it is very well designed from this point of view.

Comment: @VirgilLitan, ah, good stuff - sounds like solid design and we can scrap my next theory, then :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use soft start to prevent this situation . transient voltage should be ramp , not step . After battery you can use a mosfet for switching to PWM and so you can adjust your duty like ramp .(time of ramp should be similiar with time constant of RC)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! The most useful answers are accurate and readable ones. If you could improve the formatting of your answer and maybe explain a bit more, this answer would increase in value.